# Limit express-busboy to specific routes

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, middleware, busboy

I set up file uploads with express-busboy using the example from the repository [here](https://github.com/yahoo/express-busboy/)
which doesn't seem to use the normal `use()` syntax so I'm a little confused as to how to actually limit this middleware so it only executes on a specific route because it's breaking other POST requests.

This is how I configured it:

```
var busboy = require('express-busboy');

busboy.extend(app, {
    upload: true,
    path: './uploads/temp'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well since express-busboy wasn't working for me, I tried using express-fileupload instead and that seems to work now.

Answer (score 0):

In allowedPath value you can specify regex in this case limit at post route defined in express application. likes /uploads

```
busboy.extend(app, {
    upload: true,
    path: './uploads/temp',
    allowedPath: /^\/uploads$/

});
```

or other wise you can pass function

```
var options = {
        upload: true,
        path: './uploads/temp',


    };
options.allowedPath = function(url) {
    return url == '/api/ccUpload';
}

    busboy.extend(app, options);
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that's what that option did. Anyway it doesn't seem to work for me, I only want to enable busboy for the route /api/ccUpload so I did `allowedPath: '/^\/api/ccUpload$'`. The upload still works but it is still breaking my other POST routes. Did I use the correct regex?

Comment: at which exactly post route you want to upload ?

Comment: use /^\/api\/ccUpload$/ without any single or double qoutes

Comment: Nope, still having the same issue. When I remove the code I gave in my original post everything works fine. Then when I add the busboy code all my other POST requests that aren't `multipart/form-data` stop working and just hang forever and never send back a response.

Comment: Still nothing, and actually could this have anything to do with using keystone.js? In keystone I setup my middleware and other configurations on my express instance, then pass it into keystone which then handles the actual route definitions.

Comment: @chrispytoes Any luck? Having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) instead, and limit it to your route:

```
app.post('/^\/api\/ccUpload$/',
  multer({
    dest: './uploads/temp',
    rename: function(fieldname, filename, req, res) {
      return filename.toLowerCase();
    }
  }),
  yourRouteHandler
);
```